# Problem in detecting valueChange in formGroup and formArray in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a dynamic field form in which the user can add more fields. I want to detect the changes in `libId` But the changes are only detecting for the first field.

My code-

```
 this.invoiceForm = this._fb.group({
        itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRows()]) // here
      });


    (<FormArray>this.invoiceForm.get('itemRows')).controls.forEach(
      control => {
        console.log('reaches');
        control.get('libId').valueChanges
          .pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged()
          )
          .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
      }
    );

      initItemRows() {
        return this._fb.group({
          // list all your form controls here, which belongs to your form array

          libId: [null, Validators.required],
          rollNumber: [null, Validators.required]
        });
      }


  addNewRow() {
    // control refers to your formarray
    const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceForm.controls['itemRows'];
    // add new formgroup
    control.push(this.initItemRows());
  }
```

I am using this code inside the `ngOnInit`. I don't know why changes are not being detected for any other field.

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Why not handle it using the `(change)` event on the `input`?

Comment: @SiddAjmera, I tried But (change) is not working of the key press, It is only working when I click outside after value change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is example:

```
    const formGroup = this.fb.group({
        libId: [null, Validators.required],
        rollNumber: [null, Validators.required]
    });

    formGroup.controls.libId.valueChanges.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    formGroup.controls.rollNumber.valueChanges.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

    this.form = this.fb.group({
        itemRows: new FormArray([formGroup])
    });

    // I've just added another form group but this should be in method - addNewRow
    const formGroup1 = this.fb.group({
        libId: [null, Validators.required],
        rollNumber: [null, Validators.required]
    });

    formGroup1.controls.libId.valueChanges.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    formGroup1.controls.rollNumber.valueChanges.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

    (this.form.controls.itemRows as FormArray).controls.push(formGroup1);
    //

    ((this.form.controls.itemRows as FormArray).controls[0] as FormGroup).controls.libId.setValue('abc');
    ((this.form.controls.itemRows as FormArray).controls[1] as FormGroup).controls.rollNumber.setValue('xyz');
```

Feel free to ask if you have questions.